# function that covers boost::trim and accepts std::vector<std::string>

Tags: c++, boost

```cpp
void trimMyStrings(std::vector<std::string> &dataVectors) {
    for(auto &dataVector : dataVectors) {
        boost::algorithm::trim(dataVector);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::string firstWord = "   blaasldlasasdasd   ";
    std::string secondWord = "   asdasdasd    ";
    std::vector<std::string> combineWord{firstWord, secondWord};
    trimMyStrings(combineWord);
    std::cout << firstWord << "&" << "secondWord";
}
```

the code above doesn't work

no error but the `firstWord` and `secondWord` don't get trimmed on the `cout`

How do I make it work?

Comment: `combineWord` stores copies of the values, not references to the original variables.

Comment: so how do I deal with it? any other way to settle that down?

Comment: It pretty much depends on what can be changed and what is fixed in your setup.

Comment: how do I create the reference as you said before?

Comment: You can use vector of pointers, or vector of `std::ref` if you can change the `trimMyStrings` method. Or you can simply assign the changed values from inside the vector back to original variables.

Comment: any code that I can learn from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a reference to the original strings that you place into your vector.

```
std::vector<std::string*> combineWord{&firstWord, &secondWord};
```

Then for `trimMyStrings` you need to update its parameter like:

```
void trimMyStrings(std::vector<std::string*> &dataVectors)
```

Then use trim with something like:

```
boost::algorithm::trim(*dataVector);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
void trimMyStrings(std::vector<std::string> &dataVectors) {
    for (auto &dataVector : dataVectors) {
        boost::algorithm::trim(dataVector);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::string firstWord = "   first   ";
    std::string secondWord = "   second    ";
    std::vector<std::string> combineWord{ firstWord, secondWord };
    // overwirte function just trimed the vector's member, 
    // the vector's member is a the copy of the firstWord  and secondWord. 
    trimMyStrings(combineWord);
    std::cout << firstWord  << "&" << "firstWord" << std::endl;
    std::cout << combineWord[0] << "&" << "combineWord[0]" << std::endl;
    std::cout << secondWord << "&" << "secondWord " << std::endl;
    std::cout << combineWord[1] << "&" << "combineWord[1]"<< std::endl;
}
```

```
   first   &firstWord
first&combineWord[0]
   second    &secondWord
second&combineWord[1]
```

***or***

if you want change the value of member in initial_list when construct function. you can use std::forward  like this.

```
void trimMyStrings(std::vector<std::string> &dataVectors) {
    for (auto &dataVector : dataVectors) {
        boost::algorithm::trim(dataVector);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::string firstWord = "   first   ";
    std::string secondWord = "   second    ";
    // use std::foward to foward the vlaue of string.
    std::vector<std::string> combineWord{ std::forward<std::string>(firstWord), std::forward<std::string>(secondWord) };   
    trimMyStrings(combineWord);
    std::cout << firstWord << "&" << "firstWord" << std::endl;
    std::cout << combineWord[0] << "&" << "combineWord[0]" << std::endl;
    std::cout << secondWord << "&" << "secondWord " << std::endl;
    std::cout << combineWord[1] << "&" << "combineWord[1]" << std::endl;
}
```

out put :

```
&firstWord
first&combineWord[0]
&secondWord
second&combineWord[1]
```

Comment: You're using std::forward with as non deduced type. That is sn error. In a situation like that you probably meant std:: move. However after that it makes no sense the use the potentially-moved-from variables.